# How to add a javascript in jira plugin?

Tags: resources, jira

I want to use a js file in my plugin . so i add

```
<web-resource key="myresource" name="Myresource" >
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <dependency>jira.webresources:jira-global</dependency>
    <dependency>jira.webresources:autocomplete</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="test.js" location="javascripts/test.js">
      <property key="content-type" value="text/javascript"/>
    </resource> 
    <context>page</context>
</web-resource>
```

to the atlassian-plugin.xml . Then I use #requireResource("com.jira.plugin:myresource") in my gadget xml file . But it seems doesn't work . and test.js just includes alert("haha");

Does any one know how to add a external resource to the plugin ?? Thanks.

Comment: You might download the source for this plugin and see how Jamie Eichlin does it: https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/JBHV/JIRA+Behaviours+Plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the same as in confluence, your xml, should work. Except, that you could remove the *context* part:

```
<web-resource key="myresource" >
    <context>page</context>
</web-resouce>
```

The path, in *location* attribute is relative to atlassian-plugin.xml
and prefix in  *#requireResource()* is your plugins *groupId.artifactId:myresource* .
So, if your plugin pom.xml is:

```
<groupId>com.exmaple.plugin</groupId>
<artifactId>my-jira-plugin</artifactId>
```

The *#requireResource()* in your velocity template should look like this:

```
 #requireResource("com.exmaple.plugin.my-jira-plugin:myresource");
```